# открытие текущего листа

Tags: vba, visual-basic

Проблема: во втором куске кода не выполняется `Windows(CurrentFileName).Activate`, хотя в первом куске кода всё в порядке. То есть в переменной CurrentFileName во втором варианте пусто. В чём может быть причина? - подскажите пожалуйста.

```
Dim M3_FullPath As String, CurrentFileName As String

CurrentFileName = ActiveSheet.Parent.name
```

'Кусок кода 1

```
Windows(M3_FileName).Activate
Sheets("M3").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Password
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$1048576").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ArrayTM, Operator:=xlFilterValues
n = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Range("B2:Q" + CStr(n)).Copy
Windows(CurrentFileName).Activate
Sheets(nameM3).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

'Кусок кода 2

```
Windows(M3_FileName).Activate
Sheets("ТИ").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Password
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1048576").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ArrayTM, Operator:=xlFilterValues
n = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Range("B2:P" + CStr(n)).Copy
Windows(CurrentFileName).Activate
Sheets(nameDI).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Непонятно, когда Вы присваете переменной имя родительской книги... Возможно, перед обработкой второго кода переменная CurrentFileName очищается.

Comment: @vikttur, не, не очищается в том то и дело.

Comment: @vikttur, эта переменная один раз задалась и всё и используется в 4-х местах. Я вот думаю может проблема с видимостью что-то. Просто в CurrentFileName суть такая что есть книга и листы в ней, дак вот листам присваивается их родитель - то есть сама эта книга. В первом куске кода всё нормально присваивается, а во втором куске переменная пустая

Comment: Если переменная пустая - где-то обнуляется. Например, значение присваивается в одной процедуре, а используется в другой, при этом переменная уровня процедуры.

Comment: @vikttur, спасибо! Проблему решил. Оказалось вообще не в макросе дело, а в расширении файлов, которые подгружались.

Comment: Значит, не в очистке переменной дело? Переменная при подгрузке файлов сама по себе не может обнулиться. Что-то Вы недоговариваете :)

Comment: @vikttur, не в очистке да. Там суть такая что я думал макрос поломался, но оказалось что когда данные в файл вставляются, вставляются криво и в итоге результат работы макроса кривой.
Я теперь запарился над проблемой как в Excel 2010 восстановить параметры по умолчанию. Потому что когда вставляются данные в файл через макрос, вставляются не цифры, а "#Знач!".. Есть идея как такое поправить? Или как сбросить в заводские настройки эксель, должно тоже помочь по идее..